# A keyword to specify in WHERE clause to get all the data without filtering the field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have screen where user select different options to sort data in a grid given below the data is fetched asynchronously through jQuery from database.

When user selects he needs to view `user` data where `status=1`

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE status=1;
```

And same for 2, 3, 4 a variable can be passed.

But when user doesn't select anything than it should return results of all the `users`.
So is an expression or keyword that I can pass in the query that will get `ALL` the record, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE status=ANYTHING; -- EVERYTHING, ALL, ANY
```

I don't want to write a different query for each and every case, that would not be efficient and cases are also high in number as the above example is just an hypothetical example to explain my situation the real case is bit complex.

Comment: Just don't include a `WHERE` clause in cases where there is no filtering to be done?  It's not clear why you need this, and it's likely because of a design flow elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Is the column `status` nullable?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog wrote a pretty good overview of how to do this sort of thing - [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE @status is null Or status = @status
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL() or COALESCE() function. Pass NULL value in parameter for all records and write query like

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE status=ISNULL(@status,status)
```

**UPDATE :** Above query will not returns null records, so if your table have null records then you need to write query as Kaf mentioned like

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE @status is null Or status = @status
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily return *all* rows. Specifically if `status` is nullable then rows with `NULL` for that column won't be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a second parameter to the query so your where clause reads

`WHERE STATUS = @Status or @RetrieveAll=1`

Or perhaps

`WHERE Coalesce(STATUS, 0) = @Status or @RetrieveAll=1`

Comment: Did you mean "@RetrieveAll=1"?  And, why have a second parameter when you can test for "@Status IS NULL"?

Comment: I take @RetrieveAll to be a boolean so it can be either true or false.  The way I read the question, nulls are a separate issue - i.e `@Status is Null` would not return all rows.

Comment: @GIM - I just realised what you meant - yes you are right.  Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query:

> SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE **`status`!='' or `status` != null**
>   OR
>   SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE **`status` IN (1,2,3) // all status values**